# How do I debug the relationship error in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have two tables with the same agreement number as unique id, one of the table lets say table A holds all the contract region, city, etc and table B is the detailed situation (the product, cust name, order status ) of that contract so there could posibbly be more than 1 contract in table B with the same agreement number.

When I load it on power bi it shows that i cannot create relationship between these two table because one of them has to contain unique values.[THE TABLE IM TRYING TO CONNECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNRox.png)

What's going on?

I have cleaned the agreement number column from blank space.